# "halt" is not powering-off as "shutdown -h now" does.

Tags: 14.04, power-management, shutdown, arm

I have a custom ARM board running Ubuntu 14.04.4.

/etc/default/halt:

```
# Default behaviour of shutdown -h / halt. Set to "halt" or "poweroff".
HALT=poweroff
```

When I run `shutdown -h now` the system honours `/etc/default/halt` and powers off the board:

```
[ OK ] processes ended within 1 seconds...                                      
[ OK ]ctivating swap...                                                         
[ OK ]ounting local filesystems...                                              
 * Will now halt                                                                
reboot: Power down
```

When I run `halt` the system disregards `/etc/default/halt` and simply halts, running a "while(1)" loop, and does not power off.

```
[ OK ] processes ended within 1 seconds...                                      
[ OK ]ctivating swap...                                                         
[ OK ]ounting local filesystems...                                              
 * Will now halt                                                                
reboot: System halted
```

Is my understanding of the comment in `/etc/default/halt` faulty, or is there some other issue?